# UWP - INotifyPropertyChanged - PropertyChanged is always null

Tags: uwp

I have a problem.
Below is my XAML.
As you can see Pivot is bind to StoreInfos.
StoreInfos is
`private ObservableCollection<StoreInfo> StoreInfos;`
of my `public sealed partial class Widget : Page`

StoreInfo implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
SoreInfo contains property of `ObservableCollection<GameInfo> GameInfos`

```
public ObservableCollection<GameInfo> GameInfos 
        { 
            get
            {
                var result = new ObservableCollection<GameInfo>(_gameInfos.OrderByDescending(_ => _.LastUsageDataTime));
                return result;
            }
            
            set => _gameInfos = value; 
        }
```

GameInfo implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

The problem is the PropertyChanged of StoreInfo and GameInfo is always null.
How to fix it?

Note, adding new items to StoreInfos works well.

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{x:Bind StoreInfos}" >
        <Pivot.Resources>
            <helpers:GameTitleVisibilityConverter x:Key="gameTitleVisibilityConverter"/>
        </Pivot.Resources>
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:StoreInfo">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Id}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:StoreInfo">
                <Grid Name="GogLayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <GridView 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        ItemsSource="{x:Bind GameInfos}"           
                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                        ItemClick="GameInstalledCollection_RunGame"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem ="False"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0">
...
```

Comment: Can you check if  `_gameInfos` has value, and you could try set  ItemsSource="{x:Bind GameInfos}"    mode as OneWay, the default is OneTime

Comment: Do you slove this issue ?